# How do I split individual character within a list that is within a list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I am working on a project in Python, and I stumbled across this hindrance.
I have something like this:

```
[['abcde'],['bcdef']]
```

How do I make it such that it gives me this? :

```
[['a','b','c','d','e'],['b','c','d','e','f']]
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you start reading docs

```py
[list(string) for string in given_list]
```

or otherwise

```py
list(map(list,given_list))
```